# Cocoa Deep Copy Containers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary, deep-copy

I am tying to understand the example in the apple docs for deep copying an array of dictionaries [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html).

In Listing 3  A true deep copy

The example shows

```
NSArray* trueDeepCopyArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver  unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:oldArray]];
```

Notice there is no copy, mutable copy , or autorelease operators, so I am struggling to understand how this is a copy and how it gets released. In fact, if I release my implementation, it will crash. It does however work as expected, and there does not appear to be any abandoned memory using it as the example shows.

I looked the the NSUnarchiver class reference and it mentions that the unarchiveObjectWithData method creates a temporary copy of the object(s)?

Does this mean the proper implementation then is to allocate and init the new array rather than just assigning the pointer so it can be released?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are doing a deep copy by doing a full archival pass on the object graph.  Using NSArchiver enables things like automatic cyclic reference management and the objects can choose not to encode things like their delegate or they can hook stuff back up on unarchival.

For all intents and purposes, it is archival by saving something to disk and then reading it back in as a new document.  Only, instead of the disk, it is just stored in memory all the time.

It is slow, very expensive, and totally inappropriate for anything but when you **very occasionally** need to duplicate a complex object graph completely.

`unarchiveObjectWithData:` returns an auto-released object.  If you using MRC, you need to retain it if you want to keep it.  But, a better solution would be to move to ARC.

Comment: bbum I'm a little confused by the caution to use this approach. You say only on a "very occasionally". I went looking for a way to do a deep copy on an array of dictionaries, which also contains an array in each if its dictionaries, because I needed to modify the contents of the lowest level and resort it before outputting it without changing the original data. Non of the other copy mechanisms allow for that. they are all shallow and would modify the source data. This documentation specifically states to do this.  What other way would you recommend?  -Miek

Comment: @Miek I would lean to a situation specific copy algorithm that does the deep copy by explicitly walking the graph of containers and modifies as needed as it goes.  This will be far, far more efficient CPU wise and memory wise (calling -copy on an immutable object returns that object -- archive/unarchive creates a true dupe).   If you paste link to the documentation, I'll work with the author to clarify the costs inherent to archival based copying.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I did make my own deep copy. considering I was only interested in a couple of the keys for this manipulation anyway, it makes very good sense. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing on retain (or shortly after) because you did not respect Apple's stated memory management rules, which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Did you get the object from a method that contains alloc, new, copy or deepCopy in its name?  No, then it is not your responsibility to release it.

Do you want to hold on to this object?  If so, it is your responsibility to retain it.

As to why this code snippet results in a deep copy, you should read again what the archiver classes do.  They don't deal with your objects, they deal with "descriptions of the contents of your objects".  You might just as easily have done a "json import of the result of a json export" or an "xml import of an xml export".